# Maven Compile Plugin finds the dependencies but Maven Javadoc Plugin doesn't

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I try to generate the Java API documentation of a project composed of multiple sub-modules with `mvn site` but it doesn't work whereas `mvn install` works, it resolves all dependencies and it compiles successfully. `mvn site` resolves neither the dependencies that are inherited by all sub-modules in the parent pom file (including easymock) nor the dependencies specific to some sub-modules (including SWT).

I obtain the following error message:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site (default-site) on project ardor3d: Error generating maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:aggregate report: 
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /home/gouessej/Documents/programming/java/workspace/Ardor3D/ardor3d-swt/src/test/java/com/ardor3d/input/swt/TestSwtMouseWrapper.java:23: error: package org.eclipse.swt.events does not exist

I use Maven 3.6.1 with OpenJDK 11. This problem concerns the open source project [JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation](https://jogamp.org/cgit/ardor3d.git/tree/) and is reproducible with the latest source code.

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122648/maven-javadoc-plugin-aggregate-dependencies) but I don't think that the accepted answer helps in my case.

It worked with Java 8 but I'm not sure that it's the culprit.

P.S: Reverting [this change](https://jogamp.org/cgit/ardor3d.git/commit/pom.xml?id=463865beedc88817922f65f573a27ef3fe2bc0ac) and using Java 8 work around this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `<release>8</release>` by `<source>1.8</source><target>1.8</target>` and using Java 8 instead of Java 11 solve the problem. It's probably a bug of maven-javadoc-plugin with Java 11. This bug has been reported [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-620).